# Conditional Question on Survey123 Connect

Tags: regular-expression, arcgis-survey123-connect

In ArcGIS Survey123, I want my next question to appear based on to the previous question answer. I tried the expression ${previous_question} = 'true' however I don't seem to get it right. When I published the survey by applying the expression, the question seems to be missing from the whole survey.

The question: ****32. How often do you use the bus in Mena City?****

- Choice of answer:

  B)During the weekdays

  C)During weekends

  D)Everyday of the week

  E)Only when my regular transport is not available

  F)When it is a faster mode of transportation

  G)Almost never

The expression I used:  ${_33_how_often_do_you_use_the_bu} = 'Almost never'

I want the next question to be shown based on the answer from B-F

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to enter something like this in the relevant column of the question you only want to show if a certain answer is selected:

```
${_33_how_often_do_you_use_the_bu}='almost_never'
```

if you have a multi-select, then use:

```
selected(${_33_how_often_do_you_use_the_bu}, 'almost_never')
```

You need to use the name in the list in the code - not the label. I believe names in lists can't have spaces so there is an error in the 'Almost never' part of your code.